# Find account type from command line

Tags: macos, accounts

Is there a command i can run from terminal that will show what type of accounts are used

something that reports the username and type of account like below

```
/Users/fred - mobile, standard
/Users/wilma - network admin
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this command. It should display what you want.

```
/usr/bin/dscl . -read /Users/username | 
    egrep 'NFSHomeDirectory|RecordType' | tr '\n' ':' | cut -d':' -f2,5
/Users/username:Users
```

Comment: How can the account type be determined from the output of `id`?

Comment: I updated my answer, I think I misunderstood the question with my previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

Start with:

```
users
```

then:

```
id -Gn XXusernameXX | grep 'admin'
```

If you have an output, then 'XXusernameXX' is an admin account

Comment: You need to place each group on its own line. Maybe something like this-   `id -Gn XXusernameXX | tr ' ' '\n' |  grep -e '^admin'  `

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple command/utility called `dsmemberutil` that will check the group membership of a user.  Below is an example of command usage and the output of a user is a member of the group in question (admin)

```
dsmemberutil checkmembership -U username -G admin

user is a member of the group.     <------------------ Output result
```

It will also return an exit value of 0 if successful or a 1 if not meaning you can use it within `if/then` or `[[ ]]` evaluations in Bash/Zsh.